# COGNOS 11 how to set exact value as default dynamic

Tags: javascript, prompt, cognos, cognos-11

I'm facing issue on cognos 11. I have to create prompt (doesn't matter if value prompt or any other prompt type) where will be set default string value based on year and month from the other prompts. I have table where I can find those combination, year, month, promptValue. I suppose that only way is to do it by JS butI don't have skills in javascript.
Example what I need: year : 2020, month : 4  and settled default value should be: aabb , for month: 12, should be : ddcc ... and so on I have query where I'm using this table with detail filters on > ?year? , ?month?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using cascading prompts.  It does not require JS work.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=prompts-create-cascading-prompt

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=SSEP7J_11.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_define_prompt_control.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi C'est Moi, thanks for your answer but no this is not about cascade prompts. I know them and use them very often, Cascade source asked for value from the other prompt but this is not the case. My issue is that I have tree-prompt hierarchy, which has in Framework set request for an exact prompt, this prompt is used to choose a correct tree in the hierarchy.  There fore I'm looking a way how to fulfill this prompt with an exact value and this value is as a result form other quer.